# Extrapolate category from a categorical variable and apply them to another variable in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Starting from a cutted variable from a pd.DataFrame like this:

```
0          (0.999, 120.0]
1                     NaN
2         (120.0, 5760.0]
3          (0.999, 120.0]
4          (0.999, 120.0]
               ...       
465918     (0.999, 120.0]
465919     (0.999, 120.0]
465920     (0.999, 120.0]
465921     (0.999, 120.0]
465922                NaN
Name: X, Length: 465923, dtype: category
Categories (2, interval[float64]): [(0.999, 120.0] < (120.0, 5760.0]]
```

I would like to extrapolate the the category and apply them to another continous variable:

```
0         120.0
1         360.0
2         240.0
3         180.0
4          22.0
          ...  
199675    120.0
199676     84.0
199677     12.0
199678    120.0
199679     48.0
Name: Y, Length: 199680, dtype: float64
```

In order to obtain the variable Y segmented with the same class of the variable X

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to save the categories and the apply them directly to another variable through the [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) function

```
categories = db['X'].cat.categories
db['Y'] = pd.cut(db['Y'],bins = categories)
```